# horizontal barplot with gradient color fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, colorbrewer

I am trying to create horizontal bar plot and I would like to fill the bars trhough a color gradient, as in the figure and for this I wrote this script. However the error message appeared:
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
obs.: The columns inform the frequency of each species. 
Does someone here know how to creat the color gradient?

```js
Dataset <- read.csv(file = "dados_grafico_foco_barra.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
attach(Dataset)
ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie, M1_sava, fill = momento)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow = 1) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = M1_sava)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "green") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

```html
specie  momento M1_sava
S1  M1  1,00
S2  M1  0,86
S3  M1  1,00
S4  M1  1,00
S5  M1  1,00
S6  M1  0,74
S7  M1  0,39
S8  M1  0,83
S9  M1  0,83
S10 M1  0,00
S11 M1  0,70
S12 M1  0,11
S13 M1  1,00
S14 M1  0,00
S15 M1  0,00
S16 M1  0,00
S17 M1  0,00
S18 M1  0,83
S19 M1  0,00
S20 M1  0,00
S21 M1  0,00
S22 M1  0,00
S23 M1  0,00
S24 M1  0,04
S25 M1  0,00
S26 M1  0,00
S1  M2  0,33
S2  M2  0,86
S3  M2  0,39
S4  M2  0,02
S5  M2  0,07
S6  M2  0,02
S7  M2  0,87
S8  M2  0,06
S9  M2  0,63
S10 M2  0,33
S11 M2  0,91
S12 M2  0,67
S13 M2  0,18
S14 M2  0,08
S15 M2  0,00
S16 M2  0,00
S17 M2  0,00
S18 M2  0,00
S19 M2  0,08
S20 M2  0,00
S21 M2  0,04
S22 M2  0,00
S23 M2  0,00
S24 M2  0,00
S25 M2  0,00
S26 M2  0,00
S1  M3  0,04
S2  M3  0,32
S3  M3  0,02
S4  M3  0,00
S5  M3  0,00
S6  M3  0,00
S7  M3  0,96
S8  M3  0,06
S9  M3  0,18
S10 M3  0,33
S11 M3  0,63
S12 M3  1,00
S13 M3  0,00
S14 M3  0,94
S15 M3  0,17
S16 M3  0,00
S17 M3  0,41
S18 M3  0,04
S19 M3  0,44
S20 M3  0,17
S21 M3  0,02
S22 M3  0,00
S23 M3  0,00
S24 M3  0,00
S25 M3  0,00
S26 M3  0,00
S1  M4  0,00
S2  M4  0,00
S3  M4  0,00
S4  M4  0,00
S5  M4  0,00
S6  M4  0,00
S7  M4  0,89
S8  M4  0,00
S9  M4  0,03
S10 M4  0,22
S11 M4  0,41
S12 M4  0,46
S13 M4  0,00
S14 M4  0,81
S15 M4  0,39
S16 M4  0,70
S17 M4  0,70
S18 M4  0,00
S19 M4  0,87
S20 M4  0,91
S21 M4  0,33
S22 M4  0,37
S23 M4  0,24
S24 M4  0,15
S25 M4  0,00
S26 M4  0,00
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str(Dataset$M1_sava)
Factor w/ 33 levels "0,00","0,02",..: 33 27 33 33 33 24 17 26 26 1 ...
```

Moreover, `as.numeric(as.character(Dataset$M1_sava))` will generate NA's as R does not regocnise `,` as a decimal. Try

```
geom_col(aes(fill = as.numeric(gsub(',','.',Dataset$M1_sava))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the problem was a simple matter of the comma, but it went unnoticed.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. You're using `fill` twice; this is not a problem per se, but confusing because the second `fill = M1_sava` inside `geom_col` takes precedence over the `fill = momento` inside `ggplot`.
2. You erroneously use `,` instead of `.` as the decimal separator for values in column `M1_sava`.

```
df %>%
    mutate(M1_sava = as.numeric(gsub(",", "\\.", M1_sava))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(specie, M1_sava)) +
    facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow = 1) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_col(aes(fill = M1_sava)) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "green") +
    theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Maurits! Solved my problem! It was a simple matter of the comma, but it went unnoticed.
Now another question arose in fact I didn't want darker fill for the bars with a higher value, but rather a color gradient from the top to the bottom of the graphic. That is, regardless of the bar value, the color should be getting lighter trhough the topr -> bottom direction. Would you know what I should introduce in my script to plot this?

Comment: @FranBraga Can you not just use `scale_fill_gradient` and reverse the order , i.e. `scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "white")`?

Comment: Not because by this way the color will continue to be determined by the size of each specific bar and this is not what I want. In the graphic that I refer, the color gradient would start from the top down regardless of the size of the bar

Comment: @FranBraga *"[...], the color gradient would start from the top down regardless of the size of the bar"*  I have difficulties understanding what you're saying; what do you mean by size? The length of the bar? The width? You can simply re-order `specie` such that `M1_sava` increases/decreases from top to bottom. Is that what you're after?

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your atention :) 
However I don't want to re-order like you suggested, because the order that I'm applying is according to the species body mass, which doesn't have a coorelation with the LENGTH of the bar. I created a new question and put 2 figures there. So you can undertanding better what I want to do! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026353/horizontal-barplot-with-color-gradient-from-top-to-bottom-of-the-graphic

Comment: I got my answer... I just need to add geom_col(aes(fill = as.numeric(specie)))

Comment: @FranBraga Yes, Rui beat me to it. Glad it worked out.