# horizontal barplot with color gradient from top to bottom of the graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, colorbrewer

I would like to fill the bars in a gradient of color from the top to the bottom of the graphic. That is, regardless of the bar lenght, the color should be getting lighter trhough the top to the bottom direction. I created 2 SIMULATIONS in the photoshop. The first one (Fig. 1) is that ploted through the follow script (long bars are dark and short bars are light). However the seconde one (Fig. 2) is that I would like to elaborate (the top bars are dark and get lighter in the bottom direction).

[image: Fig, 1]

[image: Fig. 2]

```js
specie momento M1_sava
zr M1 1
yr M1 0.86
xr M1 1
wr M1 1
vr M1 1
ur M1 0.74
tr M1 0.39
sr M1 0.83
rr M1 0.83
qr M1 0
pr M1 0.7
or M1 0.11
nr M1 1
mr M1 0
lr M1 0
kr M1 0
jr M1 0
Ir M1 0.83
hr M1 0
Gr M1 0
fr M1 0
er M1 0
dr M1 0
cr M1 0.04
br M1 0
ar M1 0
zr M2 0.33
yr M2 0.86
xr M2 0.39
wr M2 0.02
vr M2 0.07
ur M2 0.02
tr M2 0.87
sr M2 0.06
rr M2 0.63
qr M2 0.33
pr M2 0.91
or M2 0.67
nr M2 0.18
mr M2 0.08
lr M2 0
kr M2 0
jr M2 0
Ir M2 0
hr M2 0.08
Gr M2 0
fr M2 0.04
er M2 0
dr M2 0
cr M2 0
br M2 0
ar M2 0
zr M3 0.04
yr M3 0.32
xr M3 0.02
wr M3 0
vr M3 0
ur M3 0
tr M3 0.96
sr M3 0.06
rr M3 0.18
qr M3 0.33
pr M3 0.63
or M3 1
nr M3 0
mr M3 0.94
lr M3 0.17
kr M3 0
jr M3 0.41
Ir M3 0.04
hr M3 0.44
Gr M3 0.17
fr M3 0.02
er M3 0
dr M3 0
cr M3 0
br M3 0
ar M3 0
zr M4 0
yr M4 0
xr M4 0
wr M4 0
vr M4 0
ur M4 0
tr M4 0.89
sr M4 0
rr M4 0.03
qr M4 0.22
pr M4 0.41
or M4 0.46
nr M4 0
mr M4 0.81
lr M4 0.39
kr M4 0.7
jr M4 0.7
Ir M4 0
hr M4 0.87
Gr M4 0.91
fr M4 0.33
er M4 0.37
dr M4 0.24
cr M4 0.15
br M4 0
ar M4 0
```

```html
Dataset <- read.csv(file = "data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
attach(Dataset)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie, M1_sava)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow = 1) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = M1_sava)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

Comment: Try `geom_col(aes(fill = as.numeric(specie)))`. And nice question, with data & code & expected result.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Beat me to it;-) You should post as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost there, you just got the color variable wrong.
(Also, don't `attach` data, please.)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie, M1_sava)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow = 1) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.numeric(specie))) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

[image]

**Data** in `dput` format.

```
Dataset <-
structure(list(specie = structure(c(26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 
21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 
20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 
19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 
18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ar", "br", "cr", "dr", "er", 
"fr", "Gr", "hr", "Ir", "jr", "kr", "lr", "mr", "nr", "or", "pr", 
"qr", "rr", "sr", "tr", "ur", "vr", "wr", "xr", "yr", "zr"), class = "factor"), 
    momento = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4"), class = "factor"), 
    M1_sava = c(1, 0.86, 1, 1, 1, 0.74, 0.39, 0.83, 0.83, 0, 
    0.7, 0.11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 
    0.33, 0.86, 0.39, 0.02, 0.07, 0.02, 0.87, 0.06, 0.63, 0.33, 
    0.91, 0.67, 0.18, 0.08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0.32, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.96, 0.06, 0.18, 0.33, 
    0.63, 1, 0, 0.94, 0.17, 0, 0.41, 0.04, 0.44, 0.17, 0.02, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.89, 0, 0.03, 0.22, 0.41, 
    0.46, 0, 0.81, 0.39, 0.7, 0.7, 0, 0.87, 0.91, 0.33, 0.37, 
    0.24, 0.15, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-104L))
```

Comment: Thank you Rui! I just change some details like theme (For white color also appear) and my graphic is great!! Thank you :)